# Googlemaps' map don't show on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm currently developping with Phonegap and i've got some problems with google API for maps.

Well, it run correctly on a web navigator, but every time I translate it on the emulator, the page is shown, but not the map... And I don't have any error message in the console or the logcat.

I've made all the autorization onEclipse and I can't understand why it is not working.

Here's my code :

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Esprit Citoyen</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/perso.js"></script> <!-- Affichage de la carte et gestion des pointeurs -->

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function deviceReday(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", afunction, false);
    } 

    function afunction(){
        geolocalisation()
    }

    var contentMarker;
    var lattitude; //y
    var longitude; //x


    </script>

</head>
 <body onload="deviceReday()"> 
<!--<body onload="geolocalisation()">-->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="center-wrapper"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="id1">
            <div class="center-wrapper">
            <div class="etape">Title</div><br/><br/>
                <div id="carte" style="width:500px; height:300px;" data-theme="c"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and for the js part :

```js
function geolocalisation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialiser, onError, {timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy: false});
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}



function initialiser(position) {
    lattitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude, longitude);
    var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder(); 


    var options = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    var carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), options);


    var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: carte
    });


    marqueur.setDraggable(true);


    google.maps.event.addListener(marqueur, 'dragend', function(event) {
        lattitude = event.latLng.lat();
        longitude = event.latLng.lng();

    console.log("long : " + lattitude + " lat : "+ longitude);
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude, longitude)

        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                contentMarker = results[0].formatted_address;
                infoWindow.setContent(contentMarker);
            }else {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
    });


    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content  : contentMarker,
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude, longitude)
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marqueur, 'click', function() {


        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                contentMarker = results[0].formatted_address;
                infoWindow.setContent(contentMarker);
            }else {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
        infoWindow.open(carte,marqueur);
    });
}
```

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: What are you `whitelisting`?

Comment: I've got a <access origin="*"/> in my config.xml.
I've read alot about a file named 'Cordova.plist' but I don't have one in my project (nor the Phonegap.plist file). Do I have to add a subdomain for use google API (and how to do that ? :p )

Comment: Have you registered for an API key yet? Just by looking at your code I noticed you didn't include your API key in the Google maps js file link. You can go [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) to learn how to sign up for a key.

Comment: No, I didn't do it yet. But well, I've just tried, and it change nothing about the problem, and still no error message anywhere.